# Repeating functions (or similar)

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a piece of code that I need to apply a number of times (likely a few hundred overall). I've tidied a lot of it into functions already which makes things a lot neater. But I still end up with a long list of, for example, `code(1)`, `code(2)`, `code(3)` and so on.

I have tried using sequence commands and loops (badly) but in the end I had to give up. Is there any way to tidy the repetition out of this code at all? (I can paste all the modified functions if needed but they should be irrelevant (I hope)). Thank you!

```
library(leaps)
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

source("J:/R/Functions/function_leapsSummary.R")
source("J:/R/Functions/function_plotregsubsetsMOD.R")

nbestfunc <- function(D, E, G){
  regsubsets(D~.,
             data=E,
             nbest=G)
}

setwd("J:/Academic papers/Dissertation journal paper/Version 3/New analysis/R code/Full data/SpringLIFE-ChalkRiver")

SpringLIFEChalkRiver <- read.csv("SpringLIFE-ChalkRiver.csv",header=T)
attach(SpringLIFEChalkRiver)

SPR_Q_PCA <- SpringLIFEChalkRiver[,c(3, 7, 12, 14, 16, 18)]

setwd("J:/R/Leaps")

##nbest
nb1 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 1)
nb2 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 2)
nb3 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 3)
nb4 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 4)
nb5 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 5)
nb6 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 6)
nb7 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 7)
nb8 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 8)
nb9 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 9)
nb10 <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = 10)

##df from captions and file names
NAMES <- cbind(c(
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=1", 
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=2", 
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=3",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=4",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=5",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=6",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=7",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=8",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=9",
  "Spring_VPCA_nbest=10"),
  c(
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=1.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=2.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=3.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=4.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=5.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=6.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=7.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=8.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=9.png",
    "J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=10.png"))

##calling function for each
leapsSummary(nb1, B = NAMES[1,1], C = NAMES[1,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb2, B = NAMES[2,1], C = NAMES[2,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb3, B = NAMES[3,1], C = NAMES[3,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb4, B = NAMES[4,1], C = NAMES[4,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb5, B = NAMES[5,1], C = NAMES[5,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb6, B = NAMES[6,1], C = NAMES[6,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb7, B = NAMES[7,1], C = NAMES[7,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb8, B = NAMES[8,1], C = NAMES[8,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb9, B = NAMES[9,1], C = NAMES[9,2])
dev.off()
leapsSummary(nb10, B = NAMES[10,1], C = NAMES[10,2])
```

#

Output from str(sum_list)

```
 List of 10

 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
 $ : Named int 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RStudioGD"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste or paste0 would help you a lot with you naming parts:

```
NAMES <- data.frame(paste0("Spring_VPCA_nbest=", 1:10),
               paste0("J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=", 1:10, ".png"))
```

I first started with Python so I naturally use more loops than I should for R. So while I am sure there is a better method using lapply or similar here is what I would do:

```
               nb_list <- list()
               for (i in 1:10) {
                  nb <- nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = i)
                  nb_list[[i]] <- nb
               }

               sum_list <- list()
               for (i in 1:length(nb_list)) {
                  ls <- leapsSummary(nb_list[[i]], B = NAMES[i,1], C = NAMES[i, 2])
                  sum_list[[i]] <- ls
                  dev.off()
               }

               lapply(sum_list, print)
```

In practice it is much better if you can substitute a length() or unique() call, like the second loop so that you can be a little more defensive and leave the counting to the computer.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely couldn't have come up with that yet; my abilities with loops are still a bit iffy.

Unfortunately it still doesn't quite work though. The code submits fine but it doesn't actually produce my images for some unknown reason. I have the same issue with what @Imo provided too.

Comment: Making it a for loop might help `for (i in 1:length(sum_list)) {print(sum_list[[i]])}`. If you want to give me the error message you are getting and the str(sum_list) output I can probably help more

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't help any, it just results in the same thing as before - nothing happens. I will add the output to str(sum_list) in the post, but I don't know how useful it is. (Note that the output is in RStudio but I've tried it in normal R aswell, just incase - same thing)

Comment: I suspected the issue may have been that the code was just running too quickly to generate the images (I've had issues with this before). So I wrote a new function: 
`PAUSE <- function(x)
{
  p1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(x)
  proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
}`

And then I added this line to `sum_list`: `PAUSE(0.75)`. Maybe not too elegant a method but it works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help, my code looks so much better and I've learnt a fair bit too!

Comment: Glad you figured that out, I have never seen that problem/solution before. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to store the nb#s in a named list instead of as separate objects. Something like

```
nbList <- lapply(1:10, function(i) nbestfunc(SpringChalkLife, SPR_Q_PCA, G = i))
# give list items same names as before
names(nbList) <- paste0("nb", 1:10)
```

Then you can pretty easily pop the rest into a `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq_len(10)) {
  leapsSummary(nbList[[i]], B = paste("Spring_VPCA_nbest=",i), 
               C = paste0("J:/R/Leaps/Spring_VPCA_nbest=, i, .png"))
  dev.off()
}
```

You could also refer to the nbList names, rather than their positions within the loop like `nbList[[paste0("nb",i)]]`.